# Split vector to multiple array/vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, split, type-conversion

I have problem to split a string vector to smaller integer vector\array. My input vector data looks like:

```
std::vector<std::string> v(2);
v[0] = "0 14 150";
v[1] = "1 2 220";
//...
```

I know one solution, to make three arrays and to use sstream to convert data to integer. But i want to avoid making "spaghetti" code.

Thank you,
Peter.

Comment: Do you want to [transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) `std::vector<std::string>` into `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` ?

Comment: Please  post at least real code not imaginary one that would not even compile. But better provide [mcve]

Comment: Your code won't compile. Did you mean `v[0] = "0 14 150";`? And please clarify what type(s) of container(s) do you want to get?

Comment: vector contains string data type. I want to convert it to 3 smaller arrays/vectors. Diving vevtor lenght by half don't save me.

Comment: Does your *3 smaller arrays/vectors* means `{0,1}` , `{14,2}` and `{150,220}` ?

Comment: Hiroki, no maybe i wrote it wrongly. Expected output are: thre arrays arr1[0]=0, arr2[0] =14; arr3[0] = 150, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I removed a verbose transposing function.

---

I assume that you want to convert `std::vector<std::string>` to a 2D matrix `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.
For instance, for your example, the desired result is assumed to be `arr1 = {0,1,...}`, `arr2 = {14,2,...}` and `arr3 = {150,220,...}`.

First,

- We can use `std::istream_iterator` to extract integers from strings.
- We can also apply the range constructor to create a `std::vector<int>` corresponding to each string.

So the following function would work for you and it does not seem to be a *spaghetti code* at least to me.
First, this function extract two integer arrays `{0,14,150,...}` and `{1,2,220,...}` as matrices from a passed string vector `v`.
Since a default constructed `std::istream_iterator` is an end-of-stream iterator, each range constructor reads each string until it fails to read the next value.
And finally, transposed one is returned:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
auto extractNumbers(const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> extracted;
    extracted.reserve(v.size());

    for(auto& s : v)
    {
        std::stringstream ss(s);
        std::istream_iterator<T> begin(ss), end; //defaulted end-of-stream iterator.

        extracted.emplace_back(begin, end);
    }

    // this also validates following access to extracted[0].
    if(extracted.empty()){
        return extracted;
    }

    decltype(extracted) transposed(extracted[0].size());
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<transposed.size(); ++i){
        for(std::size_t j=0; j<extracted.size(); ++j){
            transposed.at(i).push_back(std::move(extracted.at(j).at(i)));
        }
    }

    return transposed;
}
```

Then you can extract integers from a string vector as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PQuvETyOL8CU7dBx)

```
std::vector<std::string> v(n);
v[0] = "0 14 150";
v[1] = "1 2 220";
...
v[n-1] = "...";

auto matrix = extractNumbers<int>(v);
```

where **`matrix[0]` is `arr1`, `matrix[1]` is `arr2`, and so on.**
We can also quickly get internal pointers of them by `auto arr1 = std::move(matrix[0]);`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a split function at stackoverflow some time ago. Unfortunatly, I cannot post the link anymore.

```
void split(const std::string & str, std::vector<std::string>& cont, const std::string & delims)
{
    std::size_t current, previous = 0;
    current = str.find_first_of(delims);
    while (current != std::string::npos) 
    {
        cont.push_back(std::move(str.substr(previous, current - previous)));
        previous = current + 1;
        current = str.find_first_of(delims, previous);
    }
    cont.push_back(std::move(str.substr(previous, current - previous)));
}
```

I will need delimiter in your strings (seems to be backspace in your case) and call the function on each element of your string vector:

```
int main()
{
std::vector<std::string> vec{ "0 14 150","1 2 220" };
std::vector<std::vector<int>> intVec(3,std::vector<int>(vec.size()));
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    std::vector<std::string> singleStr;
    split(vec[i], singleStr, " ");
    for (int j=0; j < singleStr.size();j++)
        intVec[j][i] = (std::stoi(singleStr[j]));
}

system("pause");
}
```

A more generic solution could look like this. You can add further types to `BasicVariant`

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class BasicVariant
{
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    BasicVariant(const std::string& _str) :str(_str) {}
    BasicVariant(int value) :str(std::to_string(value)) {}
    BasicVariant(double value) :str(std::to_string(value)) {}
    inline int toInt()const { return *this; }
    inline double toDouble()const { return *this; }
    inline std::string toString()const { return *this; }
    inline bool toBool()const { return toDouble(); }
    inline operator int()const { return std::stoi(str); }
    inline operator double()const { return std::stof(str); }
    inline operator std::string()const { return str; }
    inline operator bool()const { return toDouble(); }
};


template<typename T>
void split(const std::string& str, std::vector<T>& sink, const std::string& delims)
{
    std::size_t current, previous = 0;
    current = str.find_first_of(delims);
    while (current != std::string::npos)
    {
        sink.push_back(std::move(BasicVariant(str.substr(previous, current - previous))));
        previous = current + 1;
        current = str.find_first_of(delims, previous);
    }
    sink.push_back(std::move(BasicVariant(str.substr(previous, current - previous))));
}




int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "0 14 150","1 2 220" };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> intVec(3, std::vector<int>(vec.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> row;
        split(vec[i], row, " ");
        for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++)
            intVec[j][i] = row[j];
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: it looks fine, but the 'rows' in my string vector contains 3 different int variables.

Comment: Hm ... i tried it and a single row contains three variables and the overall intVec should contain 2 elements

Comment: Sorry i missunderstood you. I updated my main function. intVec containts 3 elements {0,1},{14,2} and {150,220}

Comment: It is closer to solve my problem, thank you. Expected result should be: from vector vec[x] - > int array1[x] or int vec1[x] , int array2[x] or  int vec2[x], int array3 or int vec3[x]. Output should be like: array1[0] = 0 , array2[0] = 14, array3 [0] = 150  @StephanH could you help with it? Maybe i should put more data here to explain my problem.

Comment: Of course. Can you post the output after the second string of your vector? Is it: array1[0] = 1 , array2[0] = 2, array3 [0] = 220 If so, how do you want to store the vectors of the first string computed?

Comment: @PPeter I think we already got the result essentially same with it.

Comment: Hiroki and my solution produce this output.

Comment: @Hiroki nice solution, should be much faster than mine

Comment: Ok hf :) if you insist on independet arrays you can add something like std::vector<int> arr0(make_move_iterator(intVec[0].begin()), make_move_iterator(intVec[0].end()));

Comment: @StephanH Hmm.. transposing process in my solution may be rather verbose.

Comment: @StephanH thank you so much 2 :) :) i cannot attach more than one person per comment

Answer (score 0):

We have here some misunderstands.
Output of my program should have three arrays/vectors.

The output looks like:

```
arr1| arr1| arr3
0   | 14  | 150
1   |  2  | 220
2   |  4  | 130
```